# Change size of plot in r to square shape

Tags: r, plot

How do I change the size of a plot in r? The default is a rectangle but I want it as a square.

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5)
b = c(1,2,3,4,5)
plot(a,b)
plot(a,b,'o')
```

Output:
[image]

I want the plot to be in a square shape instead of a rectangle. Is there an argument in the plot function? Thanks!

Comment: `par(pty = "s"); plot(...)`?

Comment: Thanks Richard your comment solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I know how to save the image as a square. 
After those R commands in Rstudio.

In the plot window:
Export > Save as Image > Set the width and the height to the same number to make it a square. I usually set the width to 600 and the height to 600 to make a nice square, and it shows my long axes and title labels. > Update Preview > Save [image]